# PHP, MySQL: Issue with bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

This is the code I used to far:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name, age, something FROM MyTable WHERE MATCH (name, age) AGAINST (:value IN BOOLEAN MODE)');
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {
```

It's working very well. But now I want to add `date >= :date` in the query.

I changed the code like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name, age, something FROM MyTable WHERE MATCH (name, age) AGAINST (:value IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND date >= :date');
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array(':date' => $date));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {
```

But I'm always getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /var/www/username/html/folder/file.php:136 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/username/html/folder/file.php(136): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/username/folder/keywords.php on line 136

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either use `bindParam` or pass all parameter in the `execute(array)` dont mix the 2 methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the solution:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':value_final', $value_finial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can clarify the other hints.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This is binding `:value`. You already get that

```
$stmt->execute(array(':date' => $date));
```

This line is **overwriting** the previous line. In other words, `execute` is overwriting anything you've previously defined using `bindParam`. So bind them all using `bindParam` or bind them all using `execute`. You can't mix and match

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and get back later.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);` instead of passing array to execute()

Comment: And what to do with `(':value_final', $value_finial, PDO::PARAM_STR)`?